# To print the contents of a vector

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I want to perform a very simple task, but cannot due to an error I cannot figure out. I want to save the contents of the features detected to a vector onto a txt file using the following piece of code

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> feature_detector = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

feature_detector->detect(img, keypoints);

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < keypoints.size(); i++)
{
    ofstream outf("vector.txt", ios::app);
    outf<<"value at "<< i << " = " << keypoints.at<KeyPoint>(i)<<endl;
}
```

But I am presented with the following error:

> std::vector<_Ty>::at': function call missing argument list; use
>   '&std::vector<_Ty>::at' to create a pointer to member

I checked my syntax and cannot find anything wrong.

**Edit:** Before this I wanted to print out the contents of a matrix and this format worked perfectly for it, here is the code I used to print the contents of the matrix:

```
for(int x = 0;x < dst.rows ; x++)
{
    for( int y = 0; y < dst.cols; y++)
    {
        ofstream outf("Sample.txt", ios::app);
        outf<<"value at "<< x << "  " << y << " = " << dst.at<float>(x,y)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Where dst is a matrix consisting of float data type

Comment: `keypoints.at<KeyPoint>(i)` should simply be `keypoints.at(i)`.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried your version and still get the same error. Also I read that with using the .at operator it is advisable to specify the data type being used, thats why I wrote like that. And also based on the edit I just added.

Comment: Have you overloaded `operator<<(std::ostream&,const KeyPoint&)`? Without that, you won't be able to use the `outf << ...` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the builtin FileStorage class this was as easy as adding two lines.. I printed the vector of KeyPoints using the following lines:

```
FileStorage fs("test.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);

    fs << "meh" << keypoints;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change code to below:

```
 ofstream outf("vector.txt", ios::app);  // you don't want to open file again and again
 for(unsigned int i = 0; i < keypoints.size(); i++)
 {
     outf<<"value at "<< i << " = " << keypoints.at(i)<<endl;
 }
 outf.close();
```

as @jogojapan mentioned, overload operator<<(..) for OpenCV KeyPoint.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const KeyPoint& keypoint)
{
  // add stream keypoint member by yourself here
  out << keypoint.size;
  out << keypoint.angle;
  out << keypoint.response;
  out << keypoint.octave;
  out << keypoint.class_id;
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats a good point, I should have put that outside the loop. But that does not fix the error I get, its still there. The data type I am using is OpenCV specific, KeyPoint, can that be causing the error? Because when I use it as suggested by you I get the following error: ``'<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)``

Comment: have you defined `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const KeyPoint&);`?

Comment: Thank you.. looking into operator overloading .. the different data types along with a built in Point2f will make this difficult, there is also a built in function to write this and am also looking into that.

Answer (score 1):

Say: `outf << "value at "<< i << " = " << keypoints[i] <<endl;`

Comment: @shengy: The OP said `keypoints.at<KeyPoint>(i)`. That's different. And completely incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried without <KeyPoint> but still get the same error. Also I read that with using the .at operator it is advisable to specify the data type being used, thats why I wrote like that. And also based on the edit I just added.

Comment: @ipunished Wherever you read that, it's wrong. `at()` is not a template and it takes only one argument, you can't call it like that. I have a hard time believing that the code you edited in in the OP worked.

Comment: Oh, what I really mean is: what is the difference between keypoints.at(i) and keypoints[i]. Except for the interface.

Comment: .at(i) throw exception if i is out of range, [i] doesn't

Comment: @shengy: As billz says. Since we're already inside a loop, there's no point in using `at()`. And next time, please make your questions self-contained so they don't require three follow-ups to be clear!

Comment: @KerrekSB Im still getting the same error. I think the reason might be that the datatype used in the vector is OpenCV specific, but still it does hod data and can be used in future functions, I just want to see what the keypoints are by printing out the values. When I use it like suggested in your answer I get the following error: ``'<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)``

Comment: @ipunished: Well, it looks like you don't have a way of printing `KeyPoint` objects. That has nothing to do wit the vector, though. Try first to print even one single element. That's a separate question, though, and should be asked separately.